# Time estimator in python

Tags: python

i'm building time estimator for flights.

i'll be asking to enter date of departure and time of departure,
and also the speed of plane(miles per hour)

Console
Arrival Time Estimator

Estimated date of departure (YYYY-MM-DD): 2016-11-23

Estimated time of departure (HH:MM AM/PM): 10:30 AM

Enter miles: 200

Enter miles per hour: 65

Estimated date of arrival: 2016-11-23

Estimated time of arrival: 01:35 PM 
Continue? (y/n): y

I want to calculate time of arrival.

my code:

```
import time
edd = '2016-12-1' #Estimated date of departure (YYYY-MM-DD) 
etd = '10:30 AM'#Estimated time of departure (HH:MM AM/PM) 
miles = 200
miles per hour =65
```

from this i want to calculate `estimated date of arrival` and `estimated time of arrival`

i also want to give a switch like `Continue? (y/n):` if y is pressed it again prompts me to enter edd and etd.

> Note: For the date/time of departure and arrival, the program should use the YYYY-MM-DD format for dates and the HH:MM AM/PM format for times

Comment: look-up `timedelta` in the `datetime` library

Comment: So what is your question? Stack Overflow isn't here to do your homework for you, but we might be willing to help if you ask something specific.

Answer (score 0):

I will not try and do any homework or something for you, however, I will send you in the right direction.

For the continue(y/n) thing, that's easy just before your function install a while loop, something like:

```
continue = True    
while continue == True:
    ask = input("Continue (y/n): ")
    if ask == "n":
        continue = False
    if ask == "y":
        continue = True
```

Hope that helps for now, if you have a more specific question, do not hesitate to ask.